# gcc fatal error: no input files with libcurl

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, libcurl

I want to compile one of the examples of libcurl ([download](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/progressfunc.html)). And I try it with a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

export CC=~/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
export XTOOLS_INCLUDE=$HOME/x-tools/$($CC -dumpmachine)/include
export XTOOLS_LIB=$HOME/x-tools/$($CC -dumpmachine)/lib

$CC -I$XTOOLS_INCLUDE -L$XTOOLS_LIB progressfunc.c -I$XTOOLS_INCLUDE -L$XTOOLS_LIB -lcurl
```

Then I start the script and get the following error:

```
$ ./make.sh
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Is the last line in the shell script wrong?

EDIT #1: I changed CPP and CXX to CC.

EDIT #2: I changed XTOOLS_LIBS to XTOOLS_LIB.

Comment: Why wont you just compile it with gcc -lcurl progressfunc.c. Also, in your bash script you don't have $CXX defined.

Comment: I changed CPP and CXX to CC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libcurl depends on a lot of other libs and needs a static flag -DCURL_STATICLIB. So it's better to use pkg-config. Here is a working script. It works also with MinGW if CPP/CXX/EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX/PREFIX are set correctly and -lpthread is removed.

```
#!/bin/bash

export CC=~/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
export CXX=~/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++

export exe_suffix=""

export PREFIX=$HOME/x-libs/$($CC -dumpmachine)
#echo "--" PREFIX=$PREFIX
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig
#echo "--" PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=$PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
export CPPFLAGS=""
#echo "--" CPPFLAGS=$CPPFLAGS
export LDFLAGS=""
#echo "--" LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS
export LDLIBS="$(pkg-config --libs --static libcurl)"
#echo "--" LDLIBS=$LDLIBS
export CFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags --static libcurl)"
#echo "--" CFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
#echo "--" CXXFLAGS=$CXXFLAGS
export pkg_config_cc="$CFLAGS $LDLIBS"
#echo "--" pkg_config_cc=$pkg_config_cc
export pkg_config_cxx="$CXXFLAGS $LDLIBS"
#echo "--" pkg_config_cxx=$pkg_config_cxx
export ldflags_cc="-w -g3 -std=c11"
#echo "--" ldflags_cc=$ldflags_cc
export ldflags_cxx="-w -g3 -std=c++17"
#echo "--" ldflags_cxx=$ldflags_cxx

export command="$CC $CPPFLAGS $LDFLAGS $ldflags_cc progressfunc.c -o progressfunc-$($CC -dumpmachine)$exe_suffix $pkg_config_cc -lpthread"
echo "--" command=$command
$command
echo
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the variable `XTOOLS_LIBS` but use `XTOOLS_LIB`, that is empty. As the result the file name is treated as a libs path `-L progressfunc.c`. Be careful.

Comment: I changed XTOOLS_LIBS to XTOOLS_LIB.

Comment: @bais Simply add the command `echo` in the beginning of the last line and you will be see the real command that you try to run.